# biblioteca conio.h na linguagem C para Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

Estou programando em C no Codeblock do Ubuntu. 
Estou tentando adicionar uma biblioteca conio.h. Durante várias pesquisas encontrei um site que por questão de incompatibilidade no ubuntu com a biblioteca conio.h, um grupo criou o gconio.h. Então, devo baixar um arquivo nesse site chamado gconio.h e salvar na pasta (/usr/include), porém meu Ubuntu não está permitindo que eu salve nem copie e cole nessa pasta. Alguém pode me ajudar a entender o porque?

Site que citei acima: http://terminaldeinformacao.com/2012/08/25/programacao-gcc-gconio-h/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`conio.h` não faz parte da biblioteca padrão da linguagem C. Na verdade ela foi programada para ser usada no MS-DOS, porém você provavelmente vai querer usar [esse port](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-conioh/), que basicamente é um `conio.h` portado para Linux.

Repare que esse porte usa a biblioteca [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html) como backend, e que a menos que esteja portando uma aplicação do Borland C para o Linux, não faz sentido usar a biblioteca conio, e sim o ncurses.

Comment: Ah, Entendi. Vou procurar sobre essa biblioteca ncurses. Muito obrigada. ;)

Comment: Sim, é que eu sou iniciante no linux e além de baixar tive que pesquisar como instalar também. Mas obrigada, consegui baixar pelo seu link.

Comment: Desculpa, não sei mexer aqui direito ainda. Acho que agora aceitei. Apareceu ai?

Answer (score 2):

Você não tem permissões para colocar o ficheiro  na pasta. Para fazer tem de ir aonde baixou o `gconio.h` e correr o seguinte comando `sudo cp gconio.h /usr/include/gconio.h`.

Irá lhe pedir a password de root é so colocar e carregar enter.

Ou pode utilizar o ncurses como já foi sugerido.

Comment: Obrigada, usei o ncurses mas é sempre bom saber como fazer de outro jeito. ;)